# How to turn my Jersey REST API into an executable JAR?

Tags: rest, jersey, executable

I am using Jersey, Maven; and could use Jetty, Tomcat or J2EE Preview (is that embeddable?).

1. What is the easiest way to port my REST API as a standalone/executable JAR?
2. Can I do it without Spring Boot?

Comment: Eclipse provided lightweight server.

Comment: It could be achieved with Spring Boot and Tomcat embedded.

Comment: Thank you. How about without Spring boot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow these steps to create a standalone application with **Jersey and Tomcat**:

### Adding Maven dependencies

Add the following dependencies and properties to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>8.5.23</tomcat.version>
    <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### Creating JAX-RS resource classes

Define your JAX-RS resource class(es). The following is just an example:

```java
@Path("hello")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response helloWorld() {
        return Response.ok("Hello World").build();
    }
}
```

### Creating a Jersey configuration class

Create a class to configure your Jersey application:

```java
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfiguration() {
        packages("com.example");
    }
}
```

### Creating a launcher class for Tomcat

Create a class to launch Tomcat and deployment your application:

```java
public class Launcher {

    private static final String JERSEY_SERVLET_NAME = "jersey-container-servlet";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Launcher().start();
    }

    void start() throws Exception {

        String port = System.getenv("PORT");
        if (port == null || port.isEmpty()) {
            port = "8080";
        }

        String contextPath = "";
        String appBase = ".";

        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(port));
        tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(appBase);

        Context context = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, appBase);
        Tomcat.addServlet(context, JERSEY_SERVLET_NAME,
                new ServletContainer(new JerseyConfiguration()));
        context.addServletMappingDecoded("/api/*", JERSEY_SERVLET_NAME);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

### Adding Maven plugin for creating an executable JAR

Finally add the Maven Shade plugin to create an executable JAR, where the `mainClass` attribute references the launch class:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>tomcat-embedded-example-${project.version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.example.Launcher</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### Compiling and running the application

To compile and run the application, follow these steps:

- Open a command line window or terminal.
- Navigate to the root directory of the project, where the `pom.xml` resides.
- Compile the project: `mvn clean compile`.
- Package the application: `mvn package`.
- Look in the target directory. You should see a file with the following or a similar name: `tomcat-embedded-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.
- Change into the target directory.
- Execute the JAR: `java -jar tomcat-embedded-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.
- The application should be available at `http://localhost:8080/api/hello`.

### See more

- [How to deploy a JAX-RS application on a Java SE environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43283116/1426227)

Comment: I thought 'maven-shade-plugin' would be required in the <build> section of pom. Isn't it?

Comment: @Raúl I don't think so. I managed to run it without any additional plugins.

Comment: Don't use the assembly plugin. It will leave out required META/services files. Instead use the shade plugin that will concatenate these files. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37735728/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet That's an interesting advice. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without reflection? I want to explicitly reference `HelloWorldResource`, I don't need all that automagic.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat What do you mean by _without reflection_?

Comment: The helloworldresource is loaded by loading the classes at the specified dir. that sounds brittle to me. I’d like to explicitly refer to the resource at compile time

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps to create a standalone application with **Jersey and Jetty**:

### Adding Maven dependencies

Add the following dependencies and properties to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<properties>
    <jetty.version>9.4.7.v20170914</jetty.version>
    <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### Creating JAX-RS resource classes

Define your JAX-RS resource class(es). The following is just an example:

```java
@Path("hello")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response helloWorld() {
        return Response.ok("Hello World").build();
    }
}
```

### Creating a Jersey configuration class

Create a class to configure your Jersey application:

```java
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfiguration() {
        packages("com.example");
    }
}
```

### Creating a launcher class for Jetty

Create a class to launch Jetty and deployment your application:

```java
public class Launcher {

    private static final String JERSEY_SERVLET_NAME = "jersey-container-servlet";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Launcher().start();
    }

    void start() throws Exception {

        String port = System.getenv("PORT");
        if (port == null || port.isEmpty()) {
            port = "8080";
        }

        Server server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(port));
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/");

        ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(JERSEY_SERVLET_NAME,
                new ServletContainer(new JerseyConfiguration()));
        context.addServlet(servlet, "/api/*");

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } finally {
            server.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

### Adding Maven plugin for creating an executable JAR

Finally add the Maven Shade plugin to create an executable JAR, where the `mainClass` attribute references the launch class:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>jetty-embedded-example-${project.version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.example.Launcher</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### Compiling and running the application

To compile and run the application, follow these steps:

- Open a command line window or terminal.
- Navigate to the root directory of the project, where the `pom.xml` resides.
- Compile the project: `mvn clean compile`.
- Package the application: `mvn package`.
- Look in the target directory. You should see a file with the following or a similar name: `jetty-embedded-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.
- Change into the target directory.
- Execute the JAR: `java -jar jetty-embedded-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.
- The application should be available at `http://localhost:8080/api/hello`.

### See more

- [How to deploy a JAX-RS application on a Java SE environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43283116/1426227)