# How to generate an executable jar file for a maven servlet project in eclipse and execute a class using the jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets, executable-jar

I have a maven servlet project, and I created executable jar for that project like show in this link: [Is it possible to build a java project only once using eclipse and share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217128/is-it-possible-to-build-a-java-project-only-once-using-eclipse-and-share/35359756#35359756)

But after creating jar file I run it by using

```
java -jar Task-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I got error

> main method not found.

I am new to these concepts and I don’t know how to define main method in servlet program.

My program is

```
public class service extends HttpServlet{
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
…..
…..
}
}
```

I am using tomcat.

**Edited with info from comments**

It is possible for me to send request using postman. I want to know how to generate an executable jar file and execute a class using the jar file also by using maven profile how to export project as a executable jar and execute it, I want to know them in general I just mentioned that example code for specifying in which area Iam working

Comment: First of all - you will generally need to show more code in order to get help. Second - a Java Servlet needs to be deployed to a servlet container such as Tomcat; it cannot be run from the command line

Comment: @morsor generally please give me advice about how to generate executable jar file and execute a class using the jar file Iam working in java web application with maven servlet with tomcat on eclipse

Comment: maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846046/run-main-class-of-maven-project

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an executable JAR which exposes REST endpoints, a solution could be to use Spring Boot:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

If it MUST be a servlet, it will need to be deployed to Tomcat.

Comment: Iam using servlet and rest with jersey it is already deployed to tomcat. Can you please advice me how to do the further steps @morsor

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If it is deployed to Tomcat, you should be able to perform HTTP requests using Postman

Comment: thank you for your response.    actually it is possible for me to send request using postman. I want to know how to generate an executable jar file and execute a class using the jar file also by using maven profile how to export project as a executable jar and execute it, I want to know them in general I just mentioned that example code for specifying in which area Iam working. I want to know them in general , I am a learning student, kindly help me @morsor

Comment: Perhaps this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343021/how-to-turn-my-jersey-rest-api-into-an-executable-jar