# JSON 415 Media Type Unsupported on Azure App Services Only with Jetty

Tags: java, json, azure, jackson, jetty

I am running Jetty 9.4.5 on an Azure App Service with Jersey and Jackson.

I have run into an issue processing requests when my server is hosted on the Azure App Service, but not when running the server locally. Locally, I can send a POST request with `Content-Type: application/json` successfully. When running on Azure, the server returns a `415 Media Type Unsupported` error.

When running on Azure, the request successfully reaches my filter for the route, and I can read the entity without issue in the filter. I have set the encoding to UTF-8 for IIS in my web.config file using the globalization tag as well.

Is there anything else that Azure could be doing to interfere with this request?

Comment: Media Type Not Supported came due to in-proper format of data been passed as an body argument to the service. I don't think this problem came due to Azure services and all. Thanks :).

Comment: Please post the code you wrote then only help will be considered. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being the result of using the Maven Shade plugin to create my deployable JAR. When running the server locally, it was being run in Eclipse. When packaging the JAR, the Maven Shade plugin was combining the multiple Jersey and Jackson libraries in such a way that they were not functioning correctly.

By using Eclipse to export the JARs using `Export > Runnable JAR file` and selecting the `Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR` option, the deployment worked on Azure.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40616737/3821113) describes the issue with Maven Shade packaging.