# Unsupported media type exception while running simple rest service using grizzly HttpServer

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, grizzly

I am trying to run a simple HttpService using grizzly HttpServer and jax-rs
But my post call to the service returns Unsupported Mediatype Error(Status code 415) 
when I try to run the service by building a jar-with-dependency using maven assembly plugin, and then starting the server by running.

`java -jar my-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

The same service if I run through intellij idea works absolutely fine using the direct run button on the main method.

Any idea what could be the issue? 
I inflated the fat jar and checked that
all dependent classes are packaged.

I have tried using postman and python request library. Both lead to same issue

Comment: Could you please put the service definition and say which REST client are you using? Anyway sound like you are missing some dependency. Remember that the IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA generally solve the dependency problems for itself, then when you run the .jar maybe don't contain some necessary dependency. Hope this help.

Comment: @LuisCarlos updated the answer. I checked the classes directory inside the fat jar. Things look fine

Comment: Sound like if the service accept JSON and you're passing Text, for example. Are you sure that the media-type you're passing the data is as expected? Another workaround could be test with a simple media-type to see if is accepted and discard basic serialization/deserialization, if pass could be that you don't have a right interceptor for serialize/deserialize the data passed. Hope this help.

Comment: Along with duplicate, there is also https://stackoverflow.com/q/37735728/2587435

Comment: Following the link posted by @PaulSamsotha , changing the plugin to maven-shade-plugin instead of maven-assembly-plugin solved the issue,